# Heroku Integration with Salesforce

Tags: integration, java, heroku

Can Someone explain the main purpose of Heroku and Limitations of using it?

I have a core java project which as a end result provides an registration key of size 16 char. I want to get this functionality into salesforce. Can I put this java code on Heroku and integrate it with salesforce and get it triggered from salesforce and get the Reg key on VF page?

Comment: This is a very generic question and may be flagged as too broad. You may want to refine your question with your exact query so we can help answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is a platform to allow you to host and execute Java code. It doesn't really directly connect to Salesforce unless your using heroku connect in heroku. So if you put a web service front end to your Java app or expose the the functionally in some way over the Internet from heroku then Salesforce and communicate to it.